# Spark structured streaming write into MySQL - Nothing is being inserted into the table

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a kafka producer streaming data and I am reading that stream and trying to write into a database in MySQL but it seems like nothing is being inserted into the table. I am not able to see anything being inserted into the table. I am new to spark.

```
msql_host_name = "localhost"
msql_port_no = "3306"
msql_database_name = "orders_db"
msql_driver_class= "com.msql.jdbc.Driver"
msql_table_name = "orders"
msql_user_name = "admin"
msql_password = "admin"
msql_jbdc_url = "jbdc:mysql://" + msql_host_name + ":" + msql_port_no +"/" + msql_database_name


def save_to_mysql(current_df, epoc_id):
    db_credentails = {"user" : msql_user_name,
            "password" : msql_password,
            "driver" : msql_driver_class}
    print("Printing epoc_id: ")
    print(epoc_id)
    print(current_df.printSchema())
    processed_at = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    current_df_final = current_df\
            .withColumn("processed_at", lit(processed_at))\
            .withColumn("batch_it", lit(epoc_id))
    print(current_df_final.printSchema())
    print("Printing before Msql table save: " + str(epoc_id))
    current_df_final.write\
        .jbdc(url=msql_jbdc_url,
              table = msql_table_name,
              mode = "append",
              properties=db_credentials) 
    print("Printing after Msql table save: " + str(epoc_id))

orders_df4 \
        .writeStream \
        .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds') \
        .outputMode("update") \
        .foreachBatch(save_to_mysql)\
        .start()
```

Output:

```
orders Streaming...
in
```

This is what I am reading from the stream the schema.

```
root
 |-- vendor_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- order_id: float (nullable = true)
 |-- customer_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- item_count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- grand_total: float (nullable = true)
 |-- is_favorite: string (nullable = true)
 |-- is_rated: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vendor_rating: float (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Restaurant_Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vendor_rating_avg: double (nullable = true)
 |-- vendor_tag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vendor_tag_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- processed_at: string (nullable = false)
 |-- batch_it: integer (nullable = false)
```

This is my orders_by_cusid in MySQL

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| vendor_id         | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| order_id          | float        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| customer_id       | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| item_count        | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| grand_total       | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| is_favorite       | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| is_rated          | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| vendor_rating     | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp         | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Restaurant_Name   | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| vendor_rating_avg | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| vendor_tag        | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| vendor_tag_name   | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| processed_at      | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| batch_it          | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

This is a update i found the error it says:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'jbdc'
```

If you know anything about this please let me know.

Comment: Can you see the records when you `display`

Comment: If you are referring to the readstream data. I tried reading it into a view and displaying it and it's possible. But I want to insert that into a table in MySQL rather than a view in spark.sql. by the way this was using createOrReplaceTempView("view_name")

Answer (score 0):

You have typo here. It should be `jdbc`, not `jbdc`.